# Garage door opener won't open/close or start light when called for

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I have about a 12-13 year old Overhead Door opener. I was a dummy and left it open over night in the Arctic cold and snow we've been having. Now the contact closure for the motor won't engage the motor.

1. Pressing the light switch on our wall panel toggles the contact closure for the light. The light works fine.
2. The sensor beams seem to be fine. One is green and one is red and flashes when I break the beam.
3. Pressing the motor switch on the wall or on the remotes does not engage the contact closure for the motor or the light. The wall switch does flash as its opening the LED's circuit.

Would there be a fuse or something worse wrong? Would it be time to replace the opener entirely?

Comment: Does it make a humming noise at all? Possibly ice somewhere obstructing the trolly? Or frozen on the chain (if chain drive). What happens if you disconnect the door. Does it move freely on the track? Will the opener move trolly?

Comment: @eaglei22 no noise. the door moves freely on the track when i disconnect it from the chain

Comment: Okay. If it were me my next steps would be to unplug the opener for a few minutes and replug it in to see if it helped reset anything. Otherwise I would keep the garage door closed and try to let the temperature warm up in there with a space heater. Or if garage is attached to house leave the house door open a little. When it's a little warmer in there try again. Otherwise it's hard to say other than if blowing snow some how got into the motor and shorted something.

Comment: Is the switch on the wall wired to the opener or is it a battery-powered remote?

Comment: @brhans it’s hard wired

Comment: @eaglei22 the power cycle helped! please post it as an answer so i can send some rep your way!

Comment: Can you un-pin the motor drive from the door proper, and operate the door manually?   You realize garage doors are counterbalanced and can easily be operated by hand (if they are in working order; if they are not in working order, they are at serious risk for exploding, latent spring tension can kill.  You should work the door by hand from time to time, simply to confirm its health.)  Close the door manually, let the "weather" inside the garage normalize, and see if that helps the opener.

Comment: @Harper ive already done that and thanks to eaglei22 i'm good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like power cycling the opener was the fix.

Glad to have helped.